# Unable to load fixtures when sqlsrv driver is loaded

Tags: php, symfony

When I try to load fixtures into my local database and I have `sqlsrv.so` enabled my fixture loading fails and I get this error:

```
In PriceCalculatorService.php(87) : eval()'d code line 1:
                                
  syntax error, unexpected ':'
```

Error is useless and irrelevant, the problem is not there.

my sqlsrv.ini file:

```
; priority=20
extension=sqlsrv.so
extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so
```

If I comment it like this

```
; priority=20
#extension=sqlsrv.so
#extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so
```

Fixture loading starts working again. I need the driver running since I want use both local `mysql` and `mssql` databases.

`sqlsrv` driver is working perfectly fine, I tested it.

I'm running symfony 4.4, php 7.4.22, ubuntu 18.04 and I'm using doctrine to migrate and load fixtures into my local database.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: In `PriceCalculatorService.php(87)` how does code that you eval looks like? How does your fixtures looks like?

Comment: @Justinas like I said the error is meaningless, and the fixtures are working fine. The only problems is the `sqlsrv.so` driver that's stops the fixtures from working. I'm not trying to load fixtures or migrations to mssql database, so fixtures are not the problem here.

Comment: So maybe you have wrong extension compiled?

Comment: @Justinas what do you mean by that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was locale settings, changing my OS region to United States, solved the problem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/non-system-locale-settings?view=sql-server-ver15